# Query Builder in Developer Console

Tags: ide, developer-console, force.com-explorer

Is there a way we can build query in developer console just how we do in force.com IDE or force.com explorer.I see a query editor but not query builder in developer console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the query / SOQL capabilities of the dev console are fairly rudimentary.  Your best bet is to stick with the Eclipse plugin or look at either Workbench (http://workbench.developerforce.com) or google for Simon Fells Pocket SOQL explorer.

Comment: You can, however, go to File -> Open and open an Object. Then select rows and click the Query button right under all the rows. The will generate the query and put it in the Query Editor. Not the same as the other Query explorers, but still better than typing it all in if using the developer console.

Answer (score 0):

The Explorer Utility that's found in Ajax tools (a freebie App from SF) comes in pretty handy too if you're looking for something you can run from the UI. It will provide all the relationships you're looking for. You'll just need to add your Where, GroupBy and other clauses you need.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted this as an idea to Salesforce.
So vote for this to get it asap

[Link to Ideas](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lEXLQA2)